# How can i find the sum of the enitre column? I want to create a grand total which will calculate the whole total and return a total result

Tags: laravel-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Phh.png)

I want to create a grand total which will calculate the whole total and return a total result. Like there are 2 rows and both rows have 2 total amount so I want to calculate the whole result and want to show it to a page.

I created a total controller here is my code:

```php
class TotalController extends Controller
{
    public function showTotal(){
        $total = Total::all();
        $sales = Sale::all();
        return view('sale.index',compact('total', 'sales'));
    }

    public function getTotal(){
        $sale = Sale::all();
        $total  = DB::table('sales')->where('id' , $id)->sum('total');    
        return view('sale.index', compact('total'));
    }
}
```

Here is my databases:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('totals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('full_total');
    });
}
```

Comment: embed the image directly in the question, do not link it

Comment: and also provide your code or at least what you have tried so far (and explain better what you want, because for the moment what seems you are looking for is `->sum('total')`)

Comment: I just want to find the total amount. How many row i created it will always calculate the whole column and returns a grand total

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are trying to do.  `$sum = Total::all()->sum('full_total');` should sum all the `full_total` values, right?  Pass it to your view like `return view('sale.index', ['sum' => $sum]);` and display it like `{{ $sum }}`.

Answer (score 0):

First u will need to change the format of the database columns from string to integer before u then implement the following code to get the sum

$total = Total::all();
$sales = Sale::all();

$totalamt  = $total->sum('full_total'); 
$salesamt  = $sales->sum('full_total');

return view('sale.index',compact('totalamt', 'salesamt'));

OR

$total = Total::all();
$sales = Sale::all();

$totalamt  = $total->sum('full_total');
$salesamt  = $sales->sum('full_total');

//declare a new total variable, then convert the variables to integers before u add them
$maintotal = int($totalamt) + int($salesamt)

return view('sale.index',compact('maintotal'));